# Joomla galleryproblem

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a joomla 1.5 site and on each page I have a fading gallery,now it works on page but will not work onthe second.  I look at the source code of both page and seen the difference between the working gallery and the none working gallery.

How can I access the code to make both look the same I cannont figure out how to do this in joomla's back end.

```
<div class="park_image">

  <noscript>
     <div>ImageSlideShow requires Javascript</div>
  </noscript>

  <ul id="briask-iss7001" class="briask-iss" style="width:300px;height:200px">  
     <li><img src="/images/users/62/Belleek.jpg" alt="An Image Slideshow" /></li>
     <li><img src="/images/users/62/Belleek_1.jpg" alt="An Image Slideshow" /></li>
     <li><img src="/images/users/62/Belleek_2.jpg" alt="An Image Slideshow" /></li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var briaskPics7001 = [0];
     var briaskInstance7001 = new briaskISS(7001,0,4000,40, briaskPics7001);
  </script>
```

I want to add this code to the page that is not working and looks like this.

```
<div class="park_image">
<img src="/images/users/64/waterJD.jpg" alt="waterJD"   />
```

Comment: You really have't given enough information. For example are you using  module? A plugin? are you changing the id dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 1.5 has not been supported for about 5 years. After you upgrade to Joomla 3.4 you will find several dozen plugins to replace your old code.